# Create column names with spaces

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a DF with columns that contain spaces in their names, but an error is appearing. This is the DF I am trying to create:

```
CITY <- c('NEW YORK', 'LONDON', 'SAN FRANCISCO', 'MADRID',  'LOS ANGELES', 'LISBON', 'RIO DE JANEIRO', 'MOSCOW',  'SAO PAULO', 'TOKIO')
NEW YORK <- c(0, 700, 250, 1000, 400, 800, 430, 900, 500, 30)
LONDON <- c(700, 0, 350, 1200, 50, 110, 780, 984, 1150, 5)
SAN FRANCISCO <- c(250, 350, 0, 200, 15, 260, 305, 412, 29, 102)
MADRID <- c(1000, 1200, 200, 0, 77, 115, 225, 318, 412, 511)
LOS ANGELES <- c(400, 50, 15, 77, 0, 88, 819, 733, 978, 1001)
LISBON <- c(800, 110, 260, 115, 88, 0, 17, 3000, 1418, 735)
RIO DE JANEIRO <- c(430, 780, 305, 225, 819, 17, 0, 513, 701, 56)
MOSCOW <- c(900, 984, 412, 318, 733, 3000, 513, 0, 389, 499)
SAO PAULO <- c(500, 1150, 29, 412, 978, 1418, 701, 389, 0, 1113)
TOKIO <- c(30, 5, 102, 511, 1001, 735, 56, 499, 1113, 0)
DF <- data.frame(CITY, NEW YORK, LONDON, SAN FRANCISCO, MADRID,  LOS ANGELES, LISBON, RIO DE JANEIRO, MOSCOW,  SAO PAULO, TOKIO)
```

This is error message:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "NEW YORK"
```

How do I solve this example of my problem? The DF I'm working on has several columns like this example, so I'd like a solution suggestion that could span multiple columns.

Comment: If you want to use names in R with spaces (not just column names, any object names), you have to put `\`` around the whole name e.g. `\`NEW YORK\` <- c(0, ...`. Note that this is not recommended, you should probably just use an underscore _ instead of a space. If you need them to have spaces for displaying the table to others, just convert underscores to spaces at the very last step of your code before you display the table.

Comment: In your example, `NEW YORK <- c(0, 700, 250, 1000, 400, 800, 430, 900, 500, 30)` will give an error in R. That's not valid syntax in R. You can have names with spaces but they are very difficult to work with. Are you sure that's what you want? Something like `data.frame("NEW YORK"=1:10, check.names=FALSE)` would work for a data.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names cannot have spaces as those would be interpreted as separate tokens, that is where your error is coming from. I have modified your example to be as close as possible to what you wish:

```
CITY <- c('NEW YORK', 'LONDON', 'SAN FRANCISCO', 'MADRID',  'LOS ANGELES', 'LISBON', 'RIO DE JANEIRO', 'MOSCOW',  'SAO PAULO', 'TOKIO')
NEW_YORK <- c(0, 700, 250, 1000, 400, 800, 430, 900, 500, 30) 
LONDON <- c(700, 0, 350, 1200, 50, 110, 780, 984, 1150, 5)
SAN_FRANCISCO <- c(250, 350, 0, 200, 15, 260, 305, 412, 29, 102)
MADRID <- c(1000, 1200, 200, 0, 77, 115, 225, 318, 412, 511)
LOS_ANGELES <- c(400, 50, 15, 77, 0, 88, 819, 733, 978, 1001)
LISBON <- c(800, 110, 260, 115, 88, 0, 17, 3000, 1418, 735)
RIO_DE_JANEIRO <- c(430, 780, 305, 225, 819, 17, 0, 513, 701, 56) 
MOSCOW <- c(900, 984, 412, 318, 733, 3000, 513, 0, 389, 499)
SAO_PAULO <- c(500, 1150, 29, 412, 978, 1418, 701, 389, 0, 1113)
TOKIO <- c(30, 5, 102, 511, 1001, 735, 56, 499, 1113, 0)
DF <- data.frame(CITY, `NEW YORK` = NEW_YORK, LONDON, `SAN FRANCISCO` = SAN_FRANCISCO, MADRID,  `LOS ANGELES` = LOS_ANGELES, LISBON, `RIO DE JANEIRO` = RIO_DE_JANEIRO, MOSCOW,  `SAO PAULO` = SAO_PAULO, TOKIO, check.names = FALSE)
```

The parameter `check.names = FALSE` is to prevent R from eliminating spaces in the column names, thanks @MrFlick !

```
print(DF)
             CITY NEW YORK LONDON SAN FRANCISCO MADRID LOS ANGELES LISBON RIO DE JANEIRO MOSCOW SAO PAULO TOKIO
1        NEW YORK        0    700           250   1000         400    800            430    900       500    30
2          LONDON      700      0           350   1200          50    110            780    984      1150     5
3   SAN FRANCISCO      250    350             0    200          15    260            305    412        29   102
4          MADRID     1000   1200           200      0          77    115            225    318       412   511
5     LOS ANGELES      400     50            15     77           0     88            819    733       978  1001
6          LISBON      800    110           260    115          88      0             17   3000      1418   735
7  RIO DE JANEIRO      430    780           305    225         819     17              0    513       701    56
8          MOSCOW      900    984           412    318         733   3000            513      0       389   499
9       SAO PAULO      500   1150            29    412         978   1418            701    389         0  1113
10          TOKIO       30      5           102    511        1001    735             56    499      1113     0
```

Comment: You can pass `check.names=FALSE` to `data.frame()` to prevent spaces from being replaced by dots.